# appending Two label texts?

Tags: iphone

i want to append two label texts(which are in different colors) in One label.any help please?
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use one UILabel with two other UILabels with their own setups as a subviews. smth like this

> ```
> UILabel* mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 120, 40)];
> UILabel* firstSublabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40)];
> [firstSublabel setText:@"asd"];
> [firstSublabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
> [mainLabel addSubview:firstSublabel];
> [firstSublabel release];
> UILabel* secondSublabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 60, 40)];
> [secondSublabel setText:@"dfg"];
> [secondSublabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
> [mainLabel addSubview:secondSublabel];
> [secondSublabel release];
> [self.view addSubview:mainLabel];
> [mainLabel release];
> ```

Comment: will u give any tutorial link pls?

Answer (score 0):

Not really in a nice way.

There are some ideas for replacements in this question: [Why is there no `NSAttributedString` on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729135/)