# Multiple UILabel or just one?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a text which looks like the following,

---

### the url of the page is http://www.myurl.com, and the phone # is (999)999-9999, blah blah blah...

And I want to show it in a way such that the URL and the phone # are both in different color and bolded. Can I do it using just one UILabel control, or I need to parse them out and put them onto separate UILabel controls. (Note that the text itself could span multiple lines.) How can I do it?

---

Sorry I forgot to mention that this is for iPhone (CoCoa Touch), where the NSAttributedString is not available.

Comment: `NSAttributedString` is available in iOS 4.0 and above. If you're targeting an earlier version and don't mind sharing a single link style between phone numbers and URLs, you could just put these into a `UITextView` and set `dataDetectorTypes`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). It supports automatic data detection for things like Phone Numbers and URLs, as well as mixed styles with NSAttributedStrings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NSAttributeString to decorate your string.  There is a good explanation of how to use them here [Change the background color of a substring of a drawn NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090226/change-the-background-color-of-a-substring-of-a-drawn-nsstring/2090253#2090253)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a UIWebView, which detects both URLs and phone numbers.