# How can I put an image inline with an NSString on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uiimage, nsattributedstring

I know you can do it on Mac OS X with NSAttributedString but I haven't had much luck with that on the iPhone.

I'm trying to basically do a string like "$200" except the dollar sign is replaced by a custom symbol.

Comment: where do you want this string and image to be shown? in a table row's cell or in the normal view?

Comment: try this [using NSAttributed String to insert Image
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300427/nstextview-insert-image-in-between-text)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729135/why-no-nsattributedstring-on-the-iphone) I found regarding NSAttributedString on the iphone. Have you read through it? There're some good ideas there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a look at the Three20 library, it helps you to put HTML texts with inline images into labels and table cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom table cell and use the interface builder to layout the image and the string in the correct position, if you want to add more labels and images, feel free to do so, but remember to add value to the Tag so that you can later on set/get the values of the labels and images. Instead of using the default table cell, use this custom table cell. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do what you want to do.

but nothing is impossible friend.

One way i can sugges you the :

--> Use UIImageView for your custom image at appropriate place.

--> Take UITextField along with it to display your actual price.

it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`NSAttributedString` does not exist in UIKit on the iPhone.

If you can find a Unicode glyph to use in place of your custom symbol, that is the easiest solution. There are glyphs for every currency symbol in the world if that's what you're trying to do.

If you must use an image, you can't mix images and text with a built-in class. You will have to create your own `UIView` subclass and implement `drawRect:` yourself to draw the image and the text separately.

Comment: NSAttributedString is in iOS as of 4.0