# NSTextView insert image in between text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextview, nsimage

Is it possible to insert an image (not a background image) into an `NSTextView`? 
Something like:

```
Hi :) How are you?
```

and it should display a "smiley" image. I have an `NSTextView` and an `NSImage`.

Comment: Did you find how to add a checkbox or sth else into nstextview?

Comment: I didn't look for check box, i had to insert image only, i believe, should be feasible with NSTextView

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Insert NSImage into NSTextView:

```
NSImage * pic = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Anne/Desktop/Sample.png"];
NSTextAttachmentCell *attachmentCell = [[NSTextAttachmentCell alloc] initImageCell:pic];
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
[attachment setAttachmentCell: attachmentCell ];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSAttributedString  attributedStringWithAttachment: attachment];
[[textView textStorage] appendAttributedString:attributedString];
```

In the header file:

```
IBOutlet id textView;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, one more question is there any way to add anymore control like, if i want to add a progress bar when user wants to transfer a file

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to provide drag & drop with the image of the cell? By default if I drag it to Finder it creates an empty text file