# NSTextView Images/Attachments

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I understand NSTextView uses attachments for images inserted. Is there any way of accessing the images, or attachments, in an NSTextView?

Comment: You should be able to do this by getting the NSAttributedString and getting the attachments out of it. This may help you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300427/nstextview-insert-image-in-between-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373408/nstextview-images-attachments?noredirect=1#comment25220037_17373408), I was able to work out how to get NSImage or NSData objects from images and files that are inserted in an NSTextView. I've put my (rough, not perfect) code [on GitHub, here](https://github.com/sebj/SJKit/tree/master/SJTextViewAttachmentsController).