# how to make NSTextfield with emoticon?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, rich-text-editor, emoticons

I am trying to develop XMPP chat client on mac. 
I want to make **chat text field with emoticon** as like Skype.

I tried this way : [NSTextView insert image in between text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300427/nstextview-insert-image-in-between-text)

```
    NSMutableAttributedString* mastring = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:astring];
    NSImage * emoticon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"smile.png"];
    NSTextAttachmentCell *attachmentCell = [[NSTextAttachmentCell alloc] initImageCell:emoticon];
    NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    [attachment setAttachmentCell: attachmentCell ];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment: attachment];
    [allstring insertAttributedString:attributedString atIndex:1];
```

So I inserted emoticon image into NSTextField, but I can't copy/paste emoticon image into another NSTextfield.
Please tech me. Thanks everybody.