# Superscripted ordinal suffix in NSString

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, unicode, nsstring

Is there a way in NSString to output the st, nd, and rd but in a superscripted format? Any known unicode perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any Unicode characters for this, but it's easy enough to make an [`NSAttributedString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000036-BBCCGDBG) that will do the trick:

```
NSDictionary * superscriptAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] 
                                                         forKey:NSSuperscriptAttributeName];
NSAttributedString * st = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"st"
                                                              attributes:superscriptAttrs];

NSMutableAttributedString * premiere = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"1"];

[premiere appendAttributedString:st];
// Don't forget to release everything when you're done with it!
```

You might also want to change the font size of the superscript. This is accomplished by including the `NSFontAttributeName` in the attributes dictionary with an appropriate font object. Note that `NSAttributedString` is only available on the iPhone in iOS 4.0+, and on the iPad in 3.2+ (see comment).

Comment: iOS 3.2+ for the iPad; iOS 4.0+ for the iPhone according to [a comment on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729135/why-no-nsattributedstring-on-the-iphone/2705683#2705683).

Comment: @Bavarious: ...and this is why I need to learn to look for the tag of the OS that I don't so know much about before getting 95% of the way through answering a question! :) Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Awesome, unfortunately just realised that NSAttributedString does not inherit from NSString =( Just curious, if I happen to do this: 

NSString *string = [premiere string];

What would be the result of string? Thanks

Comment: @Ren-D: That's right. I believe that `NSAttributedString` actually wraps an `NSString`. There is a method called `string` which gives you the characters (as an `NSString`), but not the attributes.