# How to add UTF-8 characters to an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, utf-8, nsstring

I need to make chemistry formulas (SO4^2-), and the easiest way to make subscripts and superscripts seems to be adding UTF-8 characters, since `KCTSuperscriptAttributeName:` property of NSAttributedString doesn't work.

Is it possible for me to make an nsstring with normal characters and utf-8 characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [NSString Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) "NSString is implemented to represent an array of Unicode characters, in other words, a text string."

It would be convenient to write as below:
NSString* myStr = @"Any Unicode Character You Want";

Just make sure that your default text encoding is unicode.

Comment: Also, I'm not too familar with utf-8 characters, so I'm not sure whether I read this correctly, but it says [here](http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20050330194837154) that you shouldn't copy and paste characters directly into the strings. Is that true?

Comment: Hi Mahir, about the first question, you can find the setting in Xcode's preferences -- in "Text Editing" tab. The second, the site was written at 2005, and the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) was updated at 2011. Now, you can use utf-8 directly. For example: NSString* utfstr = @"中文"; NSLog(@"utf str %@",utfstr); and the result should also be "utf str 中文".

Answer (score 4):

Justin's answer is good but I think what you might really be looking for is [`NSAttributedString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (documentation linked for you) or `NSMutableAttributedString`, where you can add superscripts, subscripts, and other character styles that `NSString` by itself can't handle.

Take a look at other `NSAttributedString` questions here or via Google, like [this potentially related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194860/how-to-create-a-subscript-with-nsattributedstring) [or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555735/how-to-make-subscripts-and-superscripts-using-nsattributedstring).

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: The second link is actually another one of my questions. I've looked into the NSAttributedString docs but searching through the internet, I've found that people have been saying that the `kSuperscriptAttributeName` property of NSAttributedString doesn't work properly

Comment: I've never heard that superscript doesn't work, but I do know that [NSAttributedString is only available in iOS 4.0 & newer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905883/superscripted-ordinal-suffix-in-nsstring). Try it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That answer, though the person answering may not have noticed, uses `NSSupersciptAttributeName` which is meant for Mac OSX, not iOS (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121449/nssuperscriptattributename-show-error)

Comment: Regardless, I tried with kCTSuperscriptAttributeName in place of NSSuperscriptAttributeName, but still no results

Comment: I'm guessing you are setting up your attributed string incorrectly (perhaps in applying the superscript attribute to the wrong range?)?  Since I can't see your code, I'm not sure what the correct answer is in your particular case.  [Here is a blog post that might help you in adding attributes to specific characters](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/03/attributed-strings-in-ios.html) in an attributed string.

Answer (score 3):

yes. i assume you know the normal approach to make an `NSString` - here's one method to create an `NSString` from a utf8 string: `-[NSString initWithUTF8String:]`.