# Is NSAttributedString available before iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

I have found conflicting information on the availability of NSAttributedString for iOS versions before 6.  It is something that would be really useful if it is somewhat backwards compatible.

Here it says it is available as of iOS 4:
[Why No NSAttributedString on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729135/why-no-nsattributedstring-on-the-iphone?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

On the Apple website it says iOS 6 and later: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I tried implementing it in my code like so:

```
NSAttributedString *commentString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I really love raisins" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];
```

It works in iOS 6 but not when I try to run it in iOS 5 or iOS 5.1. I haven't tested earlier versions.

Am I just trying to use features not included in older versions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It has been around since iOS3.2. However the ability to use them within certain UI controls such as UILabel, UIButton, UITextView, etc is only available since iOS6. You can still use them using CoreText for < 6.0.

Answer (score 6):

`NSAttributeString` and the `initWithString:attributes:` method have been around since iOS 3.2 according to the iOS reference docs. Some method of `NSAttributedString` were added in iOS 4.0. All of the methods added as a `UIKit` category were added in iOS 6.0.

The problem with this line:

```
NSAttributedString *commentString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I really love raisins" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];
```

is that the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` constant wasn't added until iOS 6.0.

So while `NSAttributedString` has been around for a while, all of the useful stuff wasn't added until 6.0.

Comment: That's twice in two days that we have answered an ios question within seconds of each other. Salute.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> In iOS 6 and later you can use attributed strings to display formatted text in text views, text fields, and some other controls

It is only IOS6 afaik. The class was available prior to IOS6, but the functaionality was not available. So your final assumption is correct :)